# Prestashop: how to submit a cart in a customer tpl file?

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm developing a module and I want to submit a cart from a tpl file (cer.tpl). 
Below is the code of the form in cer.tpl.

```
<form role="form" action="{$link->getPageLink('cart')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">                
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="consulting_Info" id="consulting_Info"></textarea>
            </div>          
            <p class="hidden">
                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$static_token}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_product" value="{$product->id|intval}" id="product_page_product_id" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="add" value=1 />
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_product_attribute" id="idCombination" value=1 />
                    <input type="text" name="qty" id="quantity_wanted" class="text" value=1 />
                    <input type="text" name="test" id="test" class="text" value="TestValue" />
            </p>
            <div class="no-print">
                <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="exclusive">
                    </span>{l s='Add to cart'}</span>
                </button>
            </div>
```

And I use Tools::getValue method to get the value of 'consulting_Info' field.
In cartController.php

```html
public function init()
 {
  parent::init();
  // Send noindex to avoid ghost carts by bots
  header('X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow', true);
  // Get page main parameters
  $this->id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product', null);
  $this->id_product_attribute = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product_attribute', Tools::getValue('ipa'));
  $this->customization_id = (int)Tools::getValue('id_customization');
  $this->qty = abs(Tools::getValue('qty', 1));
  $this->id_address_delivery = (int)Tools::getValue('id_address_delivery');
**$this->consulting_Info = (int)Tools::getValue('consulting_Info');
$this->context->smarty->assign('consulting_Info', $consulting_Info);**  
  }
```

Finally, I wrote {$consulting_Info} in shopping-cart.tpl, it showed the payment page, but it didn't show the value in onsulting_Info field.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want to submit cart to cartController which is core file. I think you should make a new module in your modules folder of prestashop then in that you can write your tpl file like that:

cer.tpl:

```
        <p id=vss_buy_now" class="buttons_bottom_block no-print" style="margin-top:-210px">
            <input type="button" name="vss_buy_now" value="{l s='Add to cart' mod='your_module_name'}" class="vss_left_col" id="vss_buy_now" style="background:{$background|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'};color:{$text|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'};border:{$border|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'};"/>
        </p>
      <script>
       $( "#vss_buy_now" ).one( "click", function() {
        var id_product_attribute = document.getElementById('idCombination').value;
        var id_product = document.getElementById('product_page_product_id').value;
        var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_wanted').value;
        $.post(
                '{$link|escape:'quotes':'UTF-8'}',
                {
                    id: id_product,
                    ipa: id_product_attribute,
                    qty: quantity
                },
        function (data) {
            window.location.replace(data);
        }
        );
    });
    <script>
```

After then you have to make a front controller in your module folder like:

```
C:\wamp\www\prestashop\modules\your_module_name\controllers\front
```

Then in that make a file named:

```
C:\wamp\www\prestashop\modules\your_module_name\controllers\front\your_module_name.php
```

Then in that file you have to write code like:

your_module_name.php   //**Note that it is the file in your controller folder//

```
<?php
class Your_Module_NameYour_Module_NameModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

public function initContent()
    {
        $qty = Tools::getValue('qty');
        $id_product = Tools::getValue('id');
        $id_product_attribute = Tools::getValue('ipa');

    }

}
```

Now in that file you can get product details and you can perform operations.I hope it would help you.